# Interface builder in Eclipse for Android: how to see my activity in fullscreen?

Tags: android, eclipse, interface

I know how to have my activities in full screen for the running application.

But I'm wondering if it's possible to edit these activities with the interface builder in Eclipse without having the status bar and title bar. That would make the design work easier.

Comment: are you looking for `Windows > Hide Toolbar` ?

Comment: No, I meant hiding top of the interface of the activity. In fullscreen app, I don't want to see status and title bars when I'm designing them with the interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

just change the theme for current activity in eclipse help u see in full-Screen. U may also set the theme as your application theme to make your application run in full screen without additional coding.

Comment: what to do when you have a custom app theme?

Comment: When creating custom theme use full screen theme as your parent theme. Then set your own custom theme as in the screen.